# Azure data factory - collapse row to one column

Tags: sql, azure, azure-data-factory

I have below input

```
A  C

1  X

1  Y

1  Z

2  D

2   E

2   F
```

where  A & C are header, I want to collapse C into one column say "B"

like below

```
A  B
1  x,y,z
2  D,E,F
```

how can we achieve in Azure data factory

Comment: which sql engine on azure?

Comment: Looking to achieve this via azure data factory

Comment: Azure Data Factory can call stored procedures. So if this data already exists in a table, call a stored procedure to transform it. Otherwise you could try pivot in data flows but it's complicated and it's not exactly what you're after. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-pivot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `string_agg`

```
select
    A,
    string_agg(C, ', ') as B
from myTable
group by
    A
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it helped a lot, I ended up using "aggregate" function in ADF and for the others who might visit this thread, below is the expression you can use in your ADF  toString(reduce(collect(C),'',#item+','+#acc,#result))  and using "A" as  "groupby"  selection using the above expression on column C in "aggregates" section of the function